# Adding new Apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, parameters

I have a problem with my Apex classes. I have code which would take amount and divide it by each month to have forecast. I have code:

```java
trigger Income on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        Date startDate = o.project_start_date__c;
        Date endDate = o.Project_end_date__c;
        Decimal amount = o.Amount;

        // Ensure that the start and end dates and the amount are not null
        if (startDate != null && endDate != null && amount != null) {
            // Fill the income fields based on the opportunity dates
            for(Integer i = startDate.month(); i <= endDate.month(); i++){
                Date startOfMonth = utils.firstDayOfMonth(startDate);
                Date endOfMonth = utils.lastDayOfMonth(startDate);
                if(startOfMonth < startDate) {
                    startOfMonth = startDate;
                }
                if(endOfMonth > endDate) {
                    endOfMonth = endDate;
                }
                Integer workingDays = utils.calculateWorkingDays(startOfMonth, endOfMonth);
                Decimal monthlyIncome = (amount / o.Technology_1_FTE__c) * workingDays;

                // assigning the calculated income to the respective month's field
                switch on i {
                    when 1 { o.income_january__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 2 { o.February_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 3 { o.March_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 4 { o.April_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 5 { o.May_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 6 { o.June_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 7 { o.July_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 8 { o.August_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 9 { o.September_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 10 { o.October_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 11 { o.November_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                    when 12 { o.December_income__c = monthlyIncome; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I constantly have an error with `invalid parameter value on line 0`. I have absolutely idea how to debug this. All fields are verified, same goes for accessibility and still getting that damn error. Any ideas how to identify the error? API Version 58

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save this code to an `Apex Class`, you are using the wrong file type. Since you open with:

```
trigger Income on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
```

that means you should be saving it to an `Apex Trigger` instead.